# close the container class from a nested component in angular

Tags: angular

I know it sounds weird but I don't know how to title this,
basically, I have my app wrap in a class container

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="container">
  <wh-header></wh-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

this is ok but

the problem is, I have a div that should be fullwith because the background is in a different color than the body but obviously because my app is wrapped in a container class is not taking the fullwidth instead is taken the container class with

I thought, well if I start the component that I want fullwith with just:

```
</div> <!-- /container --> 
**Content here **
<div class="container">
```

everything would be solved but not.. it doesn't work on that way,
of course that I can use css but I think that is unnecessary code if I can just  close that container class before my component that would solve everything

Comment: Can you create a plnkr to explain